# How do I identify reply vs. response in a jms topic?

Tags: java, jms

Suppose both reply and request are being sent to the same topic, and now I'm subscribed to it. How do I identify which of them is which?

Comment: I would create _two_ topics. Is that an option?

Comment: No. Seems like the only option is to have some kind of object property already set on those messages, right?

Comment: It definitely seems like a _good_ option. Why not?

Comment: Specification doesn't allow it, but I suppose we could ask to change it. It's good to know there isn't a built-in way to do it, that was my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting message property on the messages which you publish to the topic. You set a string property on each message, e.g. message_type=”request” or message_type=”response”. When you consume the message on the listener you can read the property to identify if the message is request or response.

Another way of doing it is by starting two listeners with message selector properties. One which will only consume messages with message_type property as “request” and  another which will only consume messages with message_type property as “response”.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way too: The request comes in first, so I can check for a smaller timestep than the response. Which will identify it as the request.

Comment: What if you send multiple requests and it takes time to receive the response, the messages will have this order in queue: request1, request2, response1, request3, response3, response2